# How to customize display url after jquery POST?

Tags: jquery, python, django, google-app-engine, freebase

I'm using Freebase Suggest, a JQuery search form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#game-search").suggest({type:'/games/game'}).bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
    $("#game-id").val(data.id);
    $("#game-name").val(data.name);
    });
  });
</script>

<form name="input" action="/game" method="post">
  <input class="search-box" type="text" id="game-search"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="game_id" id="game-id" />
  <input type="hidden" name="game_name" id="game-name" />
  <input class="button" value="Go" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This POST will return a page that displays game data.  But I want the display url to be the permalink to this page. Right now, no matter what game is returned by searching, the url is foo.com/game, but the permalink is foo.com/game/id/mid (id and mid are reference ids).

In my Handler, I return using:

```
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, 
                                        template_values, 
                                        debug=DEBUG))
```

I suspect there is a way to redirect as well but am not familiar with how.

UDPATE: doesn't seem to be clear what I am trying to ask/do. The POST passes an id via JQuery to the handler.  The path for the POST is /game.  I want the result page to display the URL /game/id/mid, basically I want to construct and display the permalink.  Maybe this is as simple as constructing the Game object in the POST, and then redirecting to a GET (using the permalink URL structure), and then the GET renders the template.

Comment: Do you want your URLs to look like the SO urls look?

Comment: SO urls?  What does that mean?

Comment: SO == StackOverflow!  Yes, like those URLs.

Comment: Is it Freebase Suggest, not Select?

Comment: Sorry, Freebase Suggest.

Comment: Did you already answer this yourself? `self.redirect(perma_url)` sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should configure the app.yaml:

```
- url: /game/(.*?)/(.*?)
script: game/yourgame.py
```

then in your yourgame.py redirect the post to permalink url:

```
self.redirect('/game/your permalink url')
```